# Comparing and checking PHP Date()

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to compare against `date()`. I'm following along in a tutorial about how to use this function to compare the current time against the time a cache file was last modified. In the tutorial, the author uses **"10800"** as 3 hours and the code looks something like:

> (filemtime($cache) < (time()-10800))

I have no problem understanding how this comparison works but I just don't get how the the expression of time, **"10800"**, is formatted.

Just for the record I spent a solid 15 minutes looking for an answer so I'm not just being ignorant of Google haha.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in seconds,

```
3 hours = 3 * 60 * 60 = 10800 seconds
```

As [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). You neeed to subtract `10800` from it to get timestamp of time before `3 hours`.

Answer (score 2):

10800 is in seconds..

all unix timestamps are measured in seconds since the epoch... 1 being the first second of 1970.

This explains why when you have a bad strtotime value and you are interpreting it with date i.e.

```
date(strtotime("last tomorrowday"));
```

it ends up showing you 1969-12-31 ... strtotime is returning 0  and if 1 is the first second of 1970 then 0 will be interpreted as the last second of 1969

Comment: So 259200 would represent 3 days and 7889230 would represent 3 months? Sort of how like how Julian Dates Work?

Comment: correct on the days... months aren't really a fixed measure of time... but for a 1/4 of a year I can go with :)

Comment: Haha, I gotcha. That's all the clarification I needed, Thanks!